# powershell transportrule - setting multiple groups in a variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I'm trying to generate a transport rule within office 365 using powershell.  The first command does not behave as expected when executed in a powershell script.  The second command, however, succeeds when executed within the powershell manually. It seems that, when stored to a variable, only the first address provided is set and the second is ignored entirely.  Am I misusing the variable or something else in the category of "duh"?

From script:

```
$groupfilter="distribution2@foo.bar,distro@foo.bar"
set-transportrule -Identity "Filtering - Received Mail" -SentToMemberOf $groupfilter
```

Executed manually via powershell:

```
set-transportrule -Identity "Filtering - Received Mail" -SentToMemberOf distribution2@foo.bar,distro@foo.bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell `-SentToMemberOf` accepts an array. From `Help Set-TransportRule`

```
[-SentToMemberOf <RecipientIdParameter[]>]
```

You should change this line

```
$groupfilter="distribution2@foo.bar,distro@foo.bar"
```

To an *array* instead of a comma separated string.

```
$groupfilter="distribution2@foo.bar","distro@foo.bar"
```